# How can I get programmatic access to the property-column mappings of DbSet<T> types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to take any type T used in a DbSet, and that has an EntityTypeConfiguration derived class, and pull a list of mappings between the properties of T and the columns of the table it maps to. How can I do this?

Example, when my model is built using these mappings:

```
this.ToTable("VISITOR");
this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("MST_SQ");
this.Property(t => t.TitleId).HasColumnName("TITLE_CODEID");
this.Property(t => t.Surname).HasColumnName("VIS_SURNAME");
this.Property(t => t.Initials).HasColumnName("VIS_INITIALS");
this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("VIS_FIRSTNAME");
```

I want to be able to determine a list of CLR Type/PropertyName == DB Type/ColumnName tuples, like

Id:short,MST_SQ:SmallInt

etc.

Comment: Have you tried delving into the MetaData API? http://romiller.com/2013/09/24/ef-code-first-mapping-between-types-tables/

Comment: @Colin, I have tried that, and while a bit kludgy using the Edmx - not your fault - it works nicely. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It might be more useful if you posted some of your code in your own answer...